# when does input pipeline returns a new data batch?

Tags: tensorflow, input, pipeline, recurrent-neural-network

I am using an input pipeline with queues and `TFRecordReader` to read a tfrecord file and use the data directly into a `dynamic_rnn` function.
So for example if i have this last step of the input pipeline:

```
xb, yb = tf.train.shuffle_batch([x, y], batch_size, capacity, min_after_dequeue, num_threads=1)
```

and i feed xb directly to `dynamic_rnn` function i understand that it fetches a new xb every time it is run. But when exactly is that? So `dynamic_rnn` function is initialized once when i build the model, does it fetch these new xb data internally?

And if for example i specify this as sequence_length for `dynamic_rnn`, `sequence_length=xb.shape[1]` or if i do something like this `print xb`, does this mean that xb will be called and return new data two times?

Answer (score 0):

`.shape` on a `Tensor` does not run it when graph building, nor does `print`, those just fetch Python metadata. Even then, referencing a `Tensor` multiple times gives you one value per `session.run` call (unless it's in a `tf.while_loop` or other control flow construct). `Tensor`s derived from queues included.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/threading_and_queues for details of TensorFlow queues (which is how `shuffle_batch` is implemented).